# write shell script copy one file to number of servers

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, devops, puppet-enterprise

i am searching in google but i can.t find that.i want a Successful shell script and using for loop.most of the case fails for searching this things.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rirPu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can two scripts:
1. Server List, this can contain a list of destination hostnames each one on a new line.
2. A copy script, which can basically cat the above server list and then execute scp command to copy the file for the same. It can also accept parameters if your server list is different per every application. Below is a sample:

```
Usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 [-a application] [-l level]"
    echo " where application = {a, b, c , d }"
    exit 1;
}   
SERVER_LIST=a.txt

for HOST in `cat $SERVER_LIST | grep -v ^# | cut -d: -f2`
do 
spawn /usr/bin/scp FILE user@$HOST:destinationDirectory
expect {
"*password:*" { send $PASSWORD\r;interact }
}
exit
"
done
```